# Синтаксическая ошибка qtranslate

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Добрый день! Не могу добавить несколько языков в строку с помощью плагина qtranslate.

```
echo '<a href="'.$more.'" class="more"><?= __('[:ru]далее:[:en]more[:es]más');?></a>';
```

Синтаксическая ошибка. Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Comment: О, ужас. в функциях вида `_()` задаётся оригинал фразы на  англ.. А плагин (точнее ВП по указанию плагнина) уже возьмёт нужный перевод из лангпака. Срочно учить матчасть!!

Answer (score 0):

У вас вывод функции в одинарных ковычках. Попробуйте так:

```
echo '<a href="'.$more.'" class="more">'. __('[:ru]далее:[:en]more[:es]más') .'</a>';
```

Comment: Ошибка пропала, ссылка выводится, в коде её видно, но без текста. Текст закомментирован

Comment: @Максим Богданов я ошибся сперва, перепутал вывод в шаблоне и в статье из админки

Comment: Та же история: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/kep/public_html/wp-content/themes/kepua/functions.php on line 354

Comment: мы писали мы писали, наши пальчики устали... пробуйте вариант

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант сработал!)